# windbg stopped after I set up a breakpoint, keeping busing

Tags: x86, windbg, breakpoint

I'm studying reverse engineering, I wrote the following code to see how it is to pass struct variables in the disassembly.

```
struct s {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct s get_some_values(int a)
{
    struct s rt;

    rt.a = a + 1;
    rt.b = a + 2;
    rt.c = a + 3;

    return rt;
}

int main()
{
    get_some_values(4);
}
```

The env is:

- all tools installed automatically by this: http://boxstarter.org/package/url?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fireeye/flare-vm/master/flarevm_malware.ps1
- win 7 x64 (VM)
- windbg x86
- vs2017
- complied to debug, without aslr and dep
- command for the windbg after loaded the executable:

  - 0:000> bl
  - 0:000> x *!main
  - 00411770          returnvalue!main ()
  - 0:000> bp 0x00411770

Since then, at the left corner of windbg, its "BUSY", and not responding to any commands like 'g'.

Here's the screenshot:
[image: windbg stopped]

Any idea what I'm facing now?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't that easier to use **"bu YourModuleName!main"**?

Comment: returnvalue!main does not appear to be a correct symbol  if you are looking to set a bp on functiion main of the exe it should be yourmodname!main where yourmodname is the actual modulename liike foo blah bar or whatever